# Sql - count the number of occurence for each duplicate value

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Here's my sample database]

Edit: What I want is to rank the frequency of all duplicates. I tried to use the code suggested earlier:

```
SELECT 
t.*,
@rn:=IF(@name = name,
    @rn + 1,
    IF(@name:=name, 1, 1)) freq
        FROM
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
    student
ORDER BY name) t
    CROSS JOIN
(SELECT @name:=NULL, @rn:=0) t2;
```

This, however, were able to count the frequency but only if they are consecutively ordered. See image below:

[image]

Instead of being counted as 3, number 1 under id 6 was counted back to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use user variables for this:

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    @rn:=IF(@name = name,
        @rn + 1,
        IF(@name:=name, 1, 1)) freq
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        student
    ORDER BY name) t
        CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @name:=NULL, @rn:=0) t2;
```

#### EDIT:

If you want to order by date and freq later, you can do:

```
select * from (
  /* the above query */
) t order by the_date_column desc, freq;
```

#### EDIT 2:

For the updated question, see below:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        t.*,
            @rn:=IF(@number = number, @rn + 1, IF(@number:=number, 1, 1)) freq
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        your_table
    ORDER BY number) t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @number:=NULL, @rn:=0) t2) t
ORDER BY id;
```

**DEMO** @ ***[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd9d9b/1)***

Comment: Thanks! That was awesome. Additional question. I have dates on each row. Is it possible to Sort the date in a descending order as well as the Frequency?

Comment: @John Updated the answer. Can you please check?

Comment: haha sorry for that, i actually had it figured out. my only concern now is where do i put say for example i want an inner join with another table. it keeps telling me duplicate column.

Comment: May I see the query which you are trying to make and what table you want to join (column names etc)? You can post it in the question.

Comment: Please edit the question and post these thing there. It's hard to understand this from comments.

Comment: Nevermind my previous question @GurV. I used your code by the way and it was awesome. But I noticed something. Please see my edits.

Comment: @John see my **EDIT 2**

Comment: same output @GurV

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    name, COUNT(*) 
FROM
    TableName 
GROUP BY
    name
```

This query should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need every occurrence of the name, so a simple group won't do. Try something like this:

```
SELECT s.name AS "Name of Student",
       (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM student ss WHERE s.name = ss.name) AS "Frequency of Late"
  FROM student s
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution

```
SELECT
    Student_Name AS StudentName,count(Student_Name) Total
FROM
    Student_Table
GROUP BY 
    Student_Name`
```